# Detect presence of String and delete all characters until end of String when String is found

Tags: java, string, str-replace

I have the following Java String :

"Hello, my name is james. See also > My name is Dan".

I would like to detect if my String contain "See also" and if it the case i would like to retrieve only the beginning of the String without text after "See also".

I would like to have "Hello, my name is james.".

How can i do that using Java ?

Comment: Yes you can. I suggest you try asking again once you have some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the rescue of homeworks...

Note that I would also append a .trim() to the last line, but its your choice.

```
public String trimSeeAlso(String string) {
    int index = string.indexOf("See also >");
    if (index < 0) return string;

    return string.substring(0, index);
}
```

Comment: Actually, a '.trimEnd()' would be better to meet the specs, but Java is not C#, so you'll have to write this one yourslef :)

Answer (score 1):

String has [indexOf(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) which will allow you to find "See also > ", and [substring(int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) with which you can extract the first and last part, by computing the indices.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using regex:

```
    public static void main(String... strings) {
    String string = "Hello, my name is james. See also > My name is Dan";
    String string2 = "Hello, my name is james. My name is Dan";
    String res[] = string.split("See also >");
    System.out.println(res[0]);
    res = string2.split("See also >");
    System.out.println(res[0]);
}
```

Output

```
Hello, my name is james. 
Hello, my name is james. My name is Dan
```

This also allows you to take all parts of the string separated by "See also > ":

```
    String string3 = "Hello, my name is james. See also > My name is Dan See also > My name is Dan";
    res = string3.split("See also >");
    for (String str: res)
        System.out.print(str + " | ");
```

Output:

```
Hello, my name is james.  |  My name is Dan  |  My name is Dan |
```

Comment: Why use a regex here? Is there any indication that actual *pattern matching* is required? It's just asking for trouble if the delimiter changes to some text that includes a character which is treated as "special" by regexes.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is by using `String`'s [`split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) function.

`split(String regex)` returns a `String[]`, so you need to access the first and only the first `String` in the `String` array

```
String newString = oldString.split("See also >")[0].trim;
```

The code above takes the old `String`:

```
"Hello, my name is james. See also > My name is Dan"
```

splits it into pieces:

```
{"Hello, my name is james. ", " My name is Dan"}
```

takes the first `String` in the array:

```
"Hello, my name is james. "
```

[`trims`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) the extra space off of it:

```
"Hello, my name is james."
```

and assigns that value to the new `String`.

Comment: As I've said in comments to other answers, I think using a regex would be a mistake here. It's all too easy to forget that it takes a regex, and end up accidentally splitting on something inappropriate. `indexOf` followed by `substring` seems much simpler to me.